# Error when tkinter quits while using Pygame

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I'm writing a game using pygame and tkinter, and when I quit using the window's cross, it throws an error (but still quits successfully):
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed
I would like to stop this error message
The code that throws the error is 'root.update'

I uploaded the code at https://gist.github.com/spacejoey86/4be3c84a32195ede0f798d3527c12874#file-second-revision

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: shortly: you should assign/bind to window's cross function which will destroy window and set your own variable `is_tk_closed = True` and later you will do `if not is_tk_closed: root.update()`. This way `root.update()` will be executed only when Tkinter window still exists.

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Your question should have enough code for us to diagnose the problem. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign function to window's cross which will set variable (ie. `tk_open`) and then you can use it to execute `root.update()` only when window still exists.

Code based on [Tkinter: Catching Window Deletion](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-window-destroy.htm) on effbot.org

You can use `root.protocol()` or `root.bind()` - read more on effbot.org

```
import tkinter as tk

def _delete_window():
    global tk_open

    print("delete_window")

    tk_open = False
    root.destroy()

def _destroy(event):
    global tk_open

    print("destroy")

    tk_open = False

root = tk.Tk()
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", _delete_window)
#root.bind("<Destroy>", _destroy)

tk_open = True

while tk_open:
    root.update()
```

Maybe in your code you will have to only set `running == False` instead of using `tk_open`.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the global bit.